# Why does the compiler issue : warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c, arrays, struct, c-strings, strcpy

I'm trying to put some information into a 2d char array. I'm putting a list of names in stdin that i'm trying to put into an array with a number corresponding to the array of characters(names). For some reason, when I try to print the names, it output some random characters.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#define NAME_MAX_LENGTH 20
#define NUM_MIN_PLAYERS 2
#define NUM_MAX_PLAYERS 20

struct PlayerList {
    unsigned int num_players;
    char name[NUM_MAX_PLAYERS][NAME_MAX_LENGTH + 1];
};

int main()  {
    int num;
    char nom[NAME_MAX_LENGTH + 1];
    struct PlayerList player;

    while(fgets(nom, sizeof nom, stdin) != NULL){
    char longueur = 0;
    player.name[num++][sizeof nom] =  nom;
    printf("%d:%s\n", num, player.name[num]);
    }
    player.num_players = num;


    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement

```
player.name[num++][sizeof nom] =  nom;
```

is incorrect.

At least you mean

```
strcpy( player.name[num++], nom );
```

To do so you need to include header

```
#include <string.h>
```

Otherwise the expression

```
player.name[num++][sizeof nom]
```

has the type `char` while the right side expression `nom` has the type `char *`.

Also this output

```
printf("%d:%s\n", num, player.name[num]);
```

has undefined behavior because the variable num was already incremented in the statement above

```
player.name[num++][sizeof nom]
            ^^^^^
```

You should write at least

```
printf("%d:%s\n", num - 1, player.name[num-1]);
```